# How to left align text in a multicolumn / tabular

Tags: horizontal-alignment, multicolumn

I have the following tex code. I cannot get the text below the "user requirement under test" to align to the left. I tried to add the \multicolumn{1}{l}{text...} however this just sends the text out of the document to the left. See picture

```
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{center}
\caption{\textit{Use Case 1 specification}} % Number of use case
\begin{tabular}{c}
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{User requirement under test:}} \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{1}{l}{The user should be able to access a interface for ordering. The interface should contain all the possible products you could potentially order, and verify if the order has been sent-} \\

\bottomrule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Stakeholders:}}\\ %List stakeholders
\toprule
\begin{minipage}[l]{\linewidth}
\begin{flushleft}
 \begin{itemize} 
    \item \textbf{Primary actor:} User
    \item \textbf{Stakeholder:} System

    
 \end{itemize}   
\end{flushleft}
\end{minipage} \\
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Preconditions:}}\\ %List preconditions
\toprule
\begin{minipage}[l]{\linewidth}
\begin{flushleft}
 \begin{itemize} 
    \item The repository has been downloaded
    \item System is turned on
    \item No errors received from any active windows 
    
 \end{itemize}   
\end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}\\
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Postcondition:}}\\ %List preconditions
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{l}{The user should be able to see an interface which is used for placing product orders.}\\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Selecting a product and sending it should put the order in the production queue} \\

% List how to set it up
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Setup:}} \\
\toprule
\begin{minipage}[l]{\linewidth}
\begin{flushleft}
 \begin{enumerate} 
    \item Open a terminal
    \item Navigate to the folder containing the file \code{GUI.py}
    \item Run the command \code{python3 GUI.py}
    \item Click an item saying "circle" or "rectangle"
    \item Click "send order" button
    
 \end{enumerate}   
\end{flushleft}
\end{minipage} \\
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Extensions:}}\\ %List preconditions
\toprule
\begin{minipage}[l]{\linewidth}
\begin{flushleft}
 \begin{itemize} 
    \item The GUI does nothing if the system, as a whole, is not running.
    \item The the product selected for the order, must have a stock above 0
    
     
 \end{itemize}   
\end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}
\end{tabular} \end{center}\end{table}
```

[image: Picture of compiled latex]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Which document class do you employ? And, how or where is `\code` defined?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  Please change the tag "align" to "horizontal-a;ignment"  "align" refers to the specifically math environment `align`.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you (a) replace `\begin{tabular}{c}` with `\begin{tabular}{@{}p{\textwidth}@{}}` (to allow automatic line wrapping) and (b) get rid of all three `\multicolumn{1}{l}` wrappers.

One more thing: The `minipage` environment knows about `t` (top), `c` (center(), and `b` (bottom) positioning specifiers. The option `l` (left??) is not recognized and is simply ignored.

I must confess that I don't understand the purpose of the `minipage` wrappers in the OP's code.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\providecommand\code[1]{\texttt{#1}} % ??

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]

\caption{\textit{Use Case 1 specification}} % Number of use case

\begin{tabular}{@{}p{\textwidth}@{}} % <-- new

\toprule % why start with "\bottomrule"?
User requirement under test \\
\midrule
The user should be able to access a interface for ordering. 
The interface should contain all the possible products you 
could potentially order, and verify if the order has been
sent- \\
\bottomrule

\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Stakeholders:}}\\ %List stakeholders
\toprule
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\begin{flushleft}
 \begin{itemize} 
    \item \textbf{Primary actor:} User
    \item \textbf{Stakeholder:} System
 \end{itemize}   
\end{flushleft}
\end{minipage} \\
\bottomrule

\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Preconditions:}}\\ %List preconditions
\toprule
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth} % "[l]" does absolutely nothing
\begin{flushleft}
 \begin{itemize} 
    \item The repository has been downloaded
    \item System is turned on
    \item No errors received from any active windows    
 \end{itemize}   
\end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}\\
\bottomrule

\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Postcondition:}}\\ %List preconditions
\toprule
The user should be able to see an interface which is used for placing product orders.\\  
Selecting a product and sending it should put the order in the production queue \\
% List how to set it up
\bottomrule

\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Setup:}} \\
\toprule
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\begin{flushleft} 
 \begin{enumerate} 
    \item Open a terminal
    \item Navigate to the folder containing the file \code{GUI.py}
    \item Run the command \code{python3 GUI.py}
    \item Click an item saying "circle" or "rectangle"
    \item Click "send order" button 
 \end{enumerate}   
\end{flushleft}
\end{minipage} \\
\bottomrule

\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Extensions:}}\\ %List preconditions
\toprule
\begin{minipage}[l]{\linewidth}
\begin{flushleft}
 \begin{itemize} 
    \item The GUI does nothing if the system, as a whole, is not running.
    \item The the product selected for the order, must have a stock above 0
\end{itemize}   
\end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}

\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```